# What means '404 2716' when trying to run JavaScript library with Django?

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I'm trying to use HighCharts with Django (with Mac Maverick). My HighCharts folder is inside my static folder. And I'm using the following template:

```
{% load static %}

<div id="categoryPieChart" 
    style="min-width: 250px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script src="{% static 'js/highcharts/highcharts.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/modules/exporting.js' %}"></script>
```

But in terminal, I get this errors. What 404 2716 means? I already checked and the file path is right.
The template just shows a blank page. What should I do?

```
[22/Dec/2013 03:00:54] "GET /Users/filipeferminiano/Documents/django/panorama/static/js/highcharts/highcharts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2716
[22/Dec/2013 03:00:54] "GET /Users/filipeferminiano/Documents/django/panorama/static/js/modules/exporting.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2704
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first number is the status code of the response: [404 Not Found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).

The second number is the number of bytes in the response. The [Django 404 error response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception) has a friendly error message for the end user, and that message has a certain length.

You misconfigured your `STATIC_URL` configuration; it should *not* be set to a filepath on your system. It only contains the *url path*.

You want to configure `STATICFILES_DIRS` instead. See the [static support configuration documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files).